# intellij Idea - How to open .css file(like application.css)?

Tags: css, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder, intellij-14

In eclipse IDE a css file named applicaion.css is opened automatically when any javafx project is opened . But in intellij idea the css file is not created automatically .

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Anyways can you clarify are you trying to create a .css or link it to your code?

Comment: As you might know that IntelliJ Idea comes in two version - CE and Ultimate (needs a license). CSS is not supported by IntelliJ Idea Community Edition (CE). If you need to get the css support, you will have get the IntelliJ Idea Ultimate edition.

Answer (score 0):

Simply right click on the package in which you would like the CSS file in and select `New -> File` then name it `application.css` or whatever name with `.css`

You then add it to the applications style sheets by:

```
layout.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/path/to/application.css")).toExternalForm();
```

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the sample folder and select New -> File.
Save the file as "name_of_your_choice.css". This is how you create a css file in javafx

[image]

You can then add the css file to your application by pasting this in your "Main.java"

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("name_of_the_css_file.css").toExternalForm());
```